# Entity Framework Include Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, dbcontext

I am currently working on a Customer Repository and I came across this issue of the include functionality not working. I was hoping that someone might be able to shed some light on why this isn't working and maybe give some feedback on how to implement this better.

```
public IQueryable<Domain.Customers.Customer> GetCustomers(params Expression<Func<Domain.Customers.Customer, object>>[] include)
{
        IQueryable<Domain.Customers.Customer> query = _context.Customers.AsNoTracking();
        foreach (var property in include)
        {
            query.Include(property);
        }
        return query;
}
```

A call to this function looks like this

```
var customer = _customerRepository.GetCustomers(p=>p.Category);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All LINQ statements return *new* `IQueryable<T>`/`IEnumerable<T>` instances. You have to keep the latest modification:

```
query = query.Include(property);
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple I was overlooking. Cheers!